# Can't show all the cyrillic content

Tags: java, jsp

I have used these imports:

`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils` `java.util.Properties,java.util.Map`

and few other package imports.

I have placed this code:
`<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>` 
and this code: `<% WebAppConfig webConf = new WebAppConfig( this.getServletContext() );

    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>`

But there are few russian characters that I can not get. I'm trying to get 2 names declared as parameters in the URL, without any luck.
The URL is not encoded/escaped.

I tried 2 ways to get the parameter without any luck.

1st I tried: `String fullName = request.getParameter("fullName");`
What I got is: `������� ����� �����������`

Then I tried to pass the variables to a bean:
`EEventBean ee = new EEventBean();` and
`ee.setFullName(request.getParameter("fullName"));`

The output was the same.

The way I'm trying to print the result is:
`<tr>
            <td width="50%">осударственного работника</td>
            <td width="50%" class="value"><%= ee.getFullName() %></td>
        </tr>`
Every russian word can be showed in the form, but I can't show the 2 parameters...
Is there a way to get the correct parameter from the URL?

EDIT: the server is `Tomcat 5.5.28`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What HTTP server are you using? It might well be failing to handle non-ASCII data when rendering JSP. Tomcat had a similar issue a few versions back: [UTF-8 encoding fix for Tomcat and JSP](http://cagan327.blogspot.ru/2006/05/utf-8-encoding-fix-tomcat-jsp-etc.html).

Comment: Most likely, it's the culprit... Try putting together an encoding filter as described in the referenced blog post.

Comment: I had same problems with jsp pages (Google App Engine).
This setup from the link helped me: "Place '<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>' as the first line in 'ALL' the jsps."